# How can I plot a continents map with R?

Tags: r, plot, maps

There are many solutions to plot maps at country level, but in my case I want to print statistics at continent level.

The only thing that comes into my mind is to use the country level maps and use a list of countries for each continent, but I was wondering if there is any simple solution for this kind of maps. To implement my idea it would be like this:

```
## produce the world map
map()
## list of countries per continent
SA <- c("argentina", "bolivia", "brazil", "chile", "colombia", "ecuador", "guyana", "paraguay", "peru", "suriname", "uruguay", "venezuela")
map(regions = SA, fill=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```

[image: worldmap]

Comment: Look for continents shape file? Without code, this is an off-topic request for a tool/library.

Comment: I'm asking for R code to produce something like the pic.

Comment: @David Ameller It'll be better to post your code so far.

Comment: Yes and as @Thomas is saying the first step is to find a shapefile for each continents (look on gadm or naturalearth for instance). Then the code is simple: you load the shapefile using `readShapeSpatial` for instance in the `sp` package and then plot them using quite simply `plot` (need package `maptools` to plot shapefiles). As it stands, since you didn't show your code so far it is not a programming question.

Comment: Ok here you can find your continent shapefiles: http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/world/continent.zip

Comment: Ok, take it easy, I'm going to put some code in a minute, sorry... :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rworldmap` has functions for plotting or aggregating data to regional levels including continents.

A simple start that should produce the plot below :

```
library(rworldmap)
#get coarse resolution world from rworldmap
sPDF <- getMap()  
#mapCountries using the 'continent' attribute  
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='continent')
```

Or for the 7 continents model :

```
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='REGION')
```

To aggregate your own data from country to regional level look at :

```
?mapByRegion
```

[image: rworldmap continent map]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible with your approach to get the 7 continents model? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent

Comment: Yes,you can use the REGION attribute instead : `mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='REGION')`. I'll add into the answer. This should also work with @Josh's excellent country merging.

Comment: I found teh output from the following code useful in understanding the various other region designators ,entioned but not detailed in ?mapByRegion: `reg<- c("GEO3", "GEO3major", "IMAGE24", "GLOCAF", "Stern", "SRES", "SRESmajor","GBD","AVOIDname"); sapply( reg, function(x) table(sPDF@data[[x]]))`

Answer (score 8):

Following up on @Andy's answer, you could merge country polygons within each continent like so:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(cleangeo)  ## For clgeo_Clean()

sPDF <- getMap()
sPDF <- clgeo_Clean(sPDF)  ## Needed to fix up some non-closed polygons 
cont <-
    sapply(levels(sPDF$continent),
           FUN = function(i) {
               ## Merge polygons within a continent
               poly <- gUnionCascaded(subset(sPDF, continent==i))
               ## Give each polygon a unique ID
               poly <- spChFIDs(poly, i)
               ## Make SPDF from SpatialPolygons object
               SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly,
                                        data.frame(continent=i, row.names=i))
           },
           USE.NAMES=TRUE)

## Bind the 6 continent-level SPDFs into a single SPDF
cont <- Reduce(spRbind, cont)

## Plot to check that it worked
plot(cont, col=heat.colors(nrow(cont)))

## Check that it worked by looking at the SPDF's data.frame
## (to which you can add attributes you really want to plot on)
data.frame(cont)
#                   continent
# Africa               Africa
# Antarctica       Antarctica
# Australia         Australia
# Eurasia             Eurasia
# North America North America
# South America South America
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh, your contribution is very helpful :)

Comment: Glad to help. The requirements that each `Polygons` object should have a unique ID and that the `SPDF`'s data.frame's rownames should match those IDs make this tricky enough that I thought I might as well document it for future reference.

Comment: Hi Josh, I am able to run your example on windows machine but not on a diff version of R and rgeos in unix. please see this link and suggest...thanks in advance..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404079/using-rgeos-library-to-merge-country-polygons

Comment: @Munish -- Looks like **rgeos** has, since this answer was originally posted, become more sensitive to non-closed polygons (or at least that's my best guess). Have now edited my answer to include a call to `cleangeo::clgeo_Clean()`, which fixes up those problems. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: hi  josh, sorry to bug but please look at this issue, kinda similar version issue of R and/or fields package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149954/image-plot-in-r-not-displaying-colorscale-values-at-the-edges-of-color-scale

Answer (score 7):

```
library(sp) #Load your libraries
library(maptools)
#Download the continents shapefile
download.file("http://baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/world/continent.zip",
              "cont.zip")
#Unzip it
unzip("cont.zip")
#Load it
cont <- readShapeSpatial("continent.shp")
#Plot it
plot(cont,
     col=c("white","black","grey50","red","blue","orange","green","yellow")) 
#Or any other combination of 8 colors
```

[image]

Comment: this solution is good, but I found that the generated PDF is too heavy. Also I found a bit tedious to have to download a shape-file from an external source (I also acknowledge it has other advantages).