# continent outlines in R

Tags: r, dictionary, rworldmap

is there a way to plot only the continental outlines of rworldmap in R (no countries, no data)?

There are two other questions close to this one, but they are to fill the continents with colors, and the commands are to plot data. 
[How can I plot a continents map with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146809/how-can-i-plot-a-continents-map-with-r)

I only want to overlay the continental outlines without country lines and without requiring other data.

Comment: You could just use [my answer to that linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20150341/980833) to get the continents' outlines in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object. Then set the plotting color to transparent, with either `plot(cont, col=NA)` or `spplot(cont, col.regions=NA)`. Alternatively, convert `cont`, a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to a `SpatialLines` object and then plot *that* with `plot()`, like so `cl <- as(cont, "SpatialLines"); plot(cl)`. Or, of course, you can add it to an existing plot with `lines(cl)`, etc., etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `coastsCoarse` data from `rworldmap`.

```
library(rworldmap)
data(coastsCoarse)
plot(coastsCoarse)
```

An example of overlaying on a gridded map.

```
mapGriddedData()
plot(coastsCoarse,add=TRUE,col='blue')
```

Comment: Great. In that case the convention is to accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following, and modify many of the aspects of the plot (title, axis text, borders, grids, etc.)

```
library(ggplot2)
countries <- map_data("world")
ggplot(countries, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(col=NA, lwd=3, fill = "white")
```

[image]

It may be possible to remove the country lines and yet keep the continent outlines if you use `geom_path`, but I tried several combinations of arguments and did not succeed:

```
ggplot(countries, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
  geom_path(col="red", lwd=0, fill = "red")
```

Comment: Did this answer work for you, or help you solve your question?