# using rgeos library to merge country polygons

Tags: r, svn

Hi I needed a worldmap in R and had it on my windows 10 machine R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) using few lines of code. rgeos version: 0.3-4, (SVN revision 438)
GEOS runtime version: 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921 
**HOWEVER, same code is NOT running** on a unix server where we recently installed R (version 3.3.2) , rgeos version: 0.3-21, (SVN revision 540),  GEOS runtime version: 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921

executing command **gUnionCascaded(sPDF)** gives error on unix machine with a diff version of rgeos package 
Error in TopologyFunc(groupID(spgeom[ids[[i]]], id[ids[[i]]]), names(ids)[i],  :  IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring.

```
#sample code:
library(rgeos)
library(rworldmap)
sPDF <- getMap()
poly_globe <- gUnionCascaded(sPDF)
plot(poly_globe)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but it also does not work anymore on my Windows box, running a 64 bit R-3.3.2 and using **rgeos** version 0.3.21.

Comment: Can you recommend any alternative approach?

Comment: Can confirm it's busted on macOS Sierra R 3.3.2, rgeos 0.3-20 as well. I also get it for `gSimplify()` and `gBuffer()`

Comment: Could possibly go this route to try to fix: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153665/29544 or use this alternate shapefile (didn't test to see if it still errors) https://github.com/ropenscilabs/rnaturalearth

Comment: @hrbrmstr Looks like in this case `cleangeo::clgeo_Clean()` also provides a quick fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, it looks like this traces to problems with the dataset provided by **rworldmap**. The problems seem to be cured by a quick application of `clgeo_Clean()` from the **cleangeo** package.

Try this to see that that's the case:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rworldmap)
library(cleangeo)
sPDF <- getMap()
sPDF <- clgeo_Clean(sPDF)
poly_globe <- gUnionCascaded(sPDF)
plot(poly_globe)
```

[image]