# Filling countries and continents with maps library according to variable value

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, maps, rworldmap

I want to fill a map with some countries from UE, and then some continents like Asia and Africa, according to my variable `prob2` values . This is my data `map_d`:

```
state prob2
<chr> <dbl>
Germany   0.6
Austria   2.9
Belgium   1.9
Bulgaria   0.6
Cyprus   0.0
Croatia   1.7
...
Other Asian   9.2
Other African   2.5
Other North American  10.7
Other Latin American   2.3
Other Oceania   5.0
```

Firstly I fill the countries of Europe, using this code:

```
europ_map <- map_data("world", region = c(
  "Germany", 
"Austria",
"Belgium",
"Bulgaria",
"Chipre",
"Croacia",
"Denmark",
"Slovakia",
"Slovenia",
"Spain",
"Estonia",
"Finland",
"France",
"Greece",
"Hungary",
"Ireland",
"Italy",
"Latvia",
"Lithuania",
"Luxembourg",
"Malta",
"Norway",
"Netherlands",
"Poland",
"Portugal",
"UK",
"Czech Republic",
"Romania",
"Sweden"))

fin_map <- merge(europ_map, map_d, by.x="region", by.y="state")
library(plyr)
fin_map <- arrange(fin_map, group, order)

ggplot(fin_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=prob2)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = "white") +
  coord_map("polyconic")
```

Which produces this map:
[Europe Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgCC6.jpg)

Now, I need to add shape of continents to my map, and fill with the value of `prob2`. Is possible?

I found in this post how to plot continents but is a different way to do: [David Ameller's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146809/how-can-i-plot-a-continents-map-with-r), and Im not able to add variable values throught this code.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, here's a starter:

```
library(tidyverse)
wm <- map_data("world")
cc <- raster::ccodes()
head(cc[,c(1:3, 8:10)], 3)
#          NAME ISO3 ISO2     UNREGION1 UNREGION2     CONTINENT
# 1       Aruba  ABW   AW     Caribbean  Americas South America
# 2 Afghanistan  AFG   AF Southern Asia      Asia          Asia
# 3      Angola  AGO   AO Middle Africa    Africa        Africa
dat <- read.csv(text="state, prob2
Other Asian,   9.2
Other African,   2.5
Other North American,  10.7
Other Latin American,   2.3
Other Oceania,   5.0")
mappings <- c("Asia"="Other Asian", "Africa"="Other African") # you add the others here
cc$MYCONTINENTS <- mappings[cc$CONTINENT]
cc <- left_join(cc, dat, by = c("MYCONTINENTS"="state"))

## 31 country names need to be mapped... 
wm$region %>% unique %>% setdiff(cc$NAME)
# ...                        
# [7] "Canary Islands"  "UK"  "Heard Island"     
# ...
## For example, UK is called United Kingdom in cc:
unique(grep("Kingdom", cc$NAME, value=T, ignore.case=T))
# [1] "United Kingdom"

mappings <- c("UK"="United Kingdom", "USA"="United States") # You add the others here
cc$NAME[match(mappings, cc$NAME)] <- names(mappings)

wm <- left_join(wm, cc[,c("NAME","MYCONTINENTS", "prob2")], by=c("region"="NAME"))
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=prob2), wm, colour = NA) +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

You'll have to map your continents to the database ones, and the country names in the database to the ones you get from `map_data`. After that, add `+ geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=prob2), wm, colour = NA)` to your code.